# Remove Project Viewer default ACL on GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I would like to delete the project-viewers default reader permissions on the objects created inside a GCS bucket.

I tried the command:

```
gsutil defacl ch -d project-viewers-3170xxxxxx:R gs://my-bucket
```

I get as a response: "No changes to gs://my-bucket".
And I do not see any changes when I do:

```
gsutil defacl get gs://my-bucket
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As per this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/iam#ch-examples) -d Removes roles granted to the specified member, try this gsutil iam ch -d group:viewers@example.com:project-viewers-3170xxxxxx gs://ex-bucket

Comment: You can remove the project-viewers default reader permissions from using GUI, Bucket >  Bucket_Name > Object_Name, click on EDIT PERMISSIONS > Delete the permission > Save

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is relevant:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#defaultobjects

In particular "The project team members group has READER permission on the object."  That is, the `READER` permissions for `project-readers-$PROJECT_NUMBER` are not controlled by the default object ACLs, they are enforced by the system.

You should try Uniform-Bucket Level Access, it might be a better match for what you are trying to achieve (maybe, I am not sure):

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access